# How to use extended class in SparseArray container?

Tags: java, polymorphism, containers

Shouldn't that be possible? If not then is there a way to do it similarly?

```
public abstract class BaseItem {
}

public class SpecificItem extends BaseItem {
    public int value;
}


public class AnAdapter{
    public AnAdapter(SparseArray<BaseItem> items){
    }
}

public class DifferenClass{
    public DifferenClass(){
        SparseArray<SpecificItem> items = new SparseArray<SpecificItem>();
        AnAdapter anAdapter = new AnAdapter(items); // here is wrong type   
    }
}
```

-------- edit:
Updated. Is it only way to append specific element to more generic container? It looks little dirty with all this casting. But works...

```
public abstract class BaseItem {
}

public class SpecificItem extends BaseItem {
    public int value;
}


public class AnAdapter{
    public AnAdapter(SparseArray<? extends BaseItem> items){
    }
}

public class DifferenClass{
    DifferenClass(){
        SparseArray<? extends BaseItem> items = new SparseArray<BaseItem>();
        ((SparseArray<SpecificItem>)items).append(0,new SpecificItem());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html)

```
public class AnAdapter{
    public AnAdapter(SparseArray<? extends BaseItem> items){
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx. Could you take a look at my updated code and tell if it's the only way to append specific element to more generic container? It looks little dirty with all this casting. But works...

Answer (score 1):

In your constructor you simply do:

```
 public class DifferenClass{
    DifferenClass(){
        SparseArray<BaseItem> items = new SparseArray<BaseItem>();
        items.append(0, new SpecificItem());
    }
}
```

Additional reading: [covariance and contravariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29)